# Display data from dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to display data from database base on what is selected from dropdown list. For example, if i choose tbl3 and click submit, all data with tbl3 must be displayed.

Expecting for an appropriate answer. Thank you, people!

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
error_reporting(0);

include("../connection/connection.php");
//
if(!isset($_SESSION['u']))
{ 
header("location../resto/index.php");
//$cust_id=!isset($_GET['cust_id'])?0:$_GET['cust_id']; 

?>
<form method="post" action="">
<p>Table No.
  <select id="cust" name ="cust">
    <?php

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT table_num, item, price, ca_id FROM tblcash WHERE  status='FINISHED' GROUP BY table_num");
$sid=!isset($_GET['id'])?0:$_GET['id'];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){


        $ca_id = $row['ca_id'];
    $lamesa = $row['table_num'];
    if($_GET['id']==$row['ca_id']){



echo "<option value=\"$ca_id\" selected>$lamesa</option>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<option value=\"$ca_id\">$lamesa</option>";
    }
}

?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="select_cust" />
</p>
<p>
  <?php

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{ 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT table_num, item, price FROM tblcash WHERE table_num=$sid AND status='FINISHED' ") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table width='400' border='1' align='center'>";
echo "<tr>";
//echo "<td>Code</td>";
echo "<td align='center' style='font-size:20px;'>Tbl #</td>";
echo "<td align='center' style='font-size:20px;'>Item</td>";
echo "<td align='center' style='font-size:20px;'>Price</td>";
echo "<tr>";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))


{

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['table_num'];
    echo "<td>" .$row['item'];
    echo "<td>" .$row['price'];
    echo "<tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
}
}
?>
</p>
<br />

  <?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$query3 = mysql_query("SELECT  SUM(price) FROM tblcash WHERE table_num=$sid AND status='FINISHED' GROUP BY table_num ");

$price = mysql_fetch_array($query3);

$price = round($price[0],2);

echo  "<div style=\"margin:0 auto;width:50%\" ><h2>TOTAL PRICE IS:$price</h2></div>";
}
?>

  <br />
  <br />
  <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])){ ?>
</p>
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:50%" ><input type="submit" name="save" value="SAVE" /></div>
<?php } ?>
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['select_cust'])){

    $selected = $_POST['cust'];
    header("location:counter2.php?id=$selected");



}


?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $customer_id = $_GET['id'];




    $query4 = mysql_query("SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM tblcash WHERE table_num=$customer_id AND status='FINISHED'  GROUP BY table_num") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($query4)>0){


    $message ='';
$test_pending=mysql_query("SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM tblcash WHERE table_num=$customer_id AND status='PENDING'  GROUP BY table_id");

if(mysql_num_rows($test_pending)>0){
    $message =' But there are dishes that are not yet cooked.';
}


    $query11 = mysql_query("SELECT  SUM(price) FROM tblcash WHERE table_num=$customer_id AND status='FINISHED'  GROUP BY table_num") or die(mysql_error());

$price1 = mysql_fetch_array($query11);

$price1 = round($price1[0],2);






    $query_delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblcash WHERE table_num=$customer_id AND status='FINISHED'") or die(mysql_error());

    if($query_delete){


        $query_get_name = mysql_query("SELECT * from tblcustomer WHERE table_num=$customer_id") or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query_get_name);

        $tbl_name = $row['table_num'];


            $query_ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblcashtrans(ca_id,table_num,total_price) VALUES ($ca_id,'$tbl_name',$price1)") or die(mysql_error());

            if($query_ins){
                 echo "<script>
                    alert(\"Successfully saved items.$message\");
                    window.location='cash2.php';
            </script>";

            }
            else{
                  echo '<script>
                    alert("Unsuccessfully saved items")
                    window.location="cash2.php";
            </script>';

            }


    }
    else{

         echo '<script>
                    alert("Unsuccessfully saved  items")
                    window.location="cash2.php";
            </script>';
        }

    }
    else{

         echo '<script>
                    alert("No Item to be saved")
                    window.location="cash2.php";
            </script>';
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: Use english language to describe your problem.

Comment: please refrain from using tagalog in stackoverlow, this is an english site. please follow the basic rules of this site

Comment: @Kim yep, and just specify the problematic part of your code that you need help. also refrain from dumping a boat load of code in your question  so that you'll get help easier

Comment: @Ghost I think my queries are quite wrong. Not so sure about my codes.

Comment: @Kim since you're problem isn't really identifiable, my advice is just take the user input (the dropdown select) and use that input to the select query. that should filter those results and just select the rows according to the user input, `select * table where column_name = input_here` or if its by table. `select * from $input_table_name` etc.

Comment: and also refrain from using mysql anymore, they are deprecated and will be obsolete in the near future. better to use mysqli or PDO